# Centos 5.10 VPS php

Tags: php, apache, centos, vps

I'm new to VPS.
I have a VPS in another country. I installed httpd and php, and created index.php in /var/www using Putty. when I run

```
php index.php
```

It runs, but when I enter the IP in the browser, It says Connection Timeout!

I Also Pasted this in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What IP? Shouldn't you just type in `localhost`?

Comment: @wavemode I mean to access from another computer. my VPS is located in another country and I access it via Putty and WinSCP.